# Using open-source ROM and social network activities

Tags: security, custom-roms

If you install a open-source ROM on your android. Can still an invisible rootkit (from manufacturer) monitor your tweets
Invisible means being invisible even in USB connection

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The manufacturer can do anything they like to the phone. There could be spyware in the radio firmware, which monitors transmitted packets. There could be a filter in the bootloader, which modifies any system image you flash to add spyware. There could be spyware in any of the closed-source drivers, which would be the same in your custom ROM as in the official image.

If you don't trust the manufacturer, don't buy their phone, but on the whole, a phone OEM monitoring your tweets is not a likely threat.